# (jQuery) - Click to drag an image but don't remove original

Tags: jquery

I'm creating somewhat of a map editor, I'd like to be able to click on an available image from the sidebar and it appears under the cursor and follows the mouse icon, so basically dragging the image, but I'd like the original image to stay put.

How would I achieve this in jQuery (preferably)?

Comment: on start drag, you can clone the element on same position, then on end drag, you just will need destroy the clone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one using jQuery UI:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Your Image</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>​
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});​
```

Here I also create the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aanred/b3QFN/. You can also read the documentation here http://jqueryui.com/draggable/.

Answer (score 1):

I think, jquery ui [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback) object will help you

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, in this example I am dragging a div, but you could just as easily check for an img child, this code prevents more than one item being dropped in (easily modified by taking out the condition), has an optional callback parameter, so that you can do something with the object just dropped (like read from the rel attribute, etc)

```
refreshDragDrop = function(dragClassName,dropDivId, callback) {
  $( "." + dragClassName ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#" + dropDivId,
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#" + dropDivId).droppable({
    accept: '.' + dragClassName,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this),
        maxItemsCount = 1;
      if ($this.children('div').length == maxItemsCount ){
        //too many items,just replace
        $(this).html($(ui.draggable).clone());
      } else {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
      }
      if (typeof callback == "function") callback($this.children('div'));
    }
  });
}
```